# How to shut down toast messages and activities

Tags: android, kill, toast

I cannot stop Toast messages that continue even when I have destroyed the activity from which they originate. They are queued and just carry on and on and on when I am in the next activity.

Comment: Could show us the code how did you raised the Toast messages and more important why you have so many of them?

Comment: This method sayHello gets called multiple times and the toast just goes on and on. I think its continues even when the Activity is destroyed but I am not 100% sure about to what degree the activity is closed.



    private void sayHello() {
        // Select a random hello.
        int helloLength = HELLOS.length;
        String hello = HELLOS[RANDOM.nextInt(helloLength)]; 
        // makeToast code
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),hello,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

     }

Answer (score 2):

You can create a object of toast and  stop it in onpause() method , but the issue is with the queued toast message . After stoping you toast object in onpause still u can see toast message
implementation:

```
Toast showToastMessage;
showToastMessage=Toast.makeText(this.this, "Toast message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
showToastMessage.show();

@Override
         protected void onPause() {
              super.onPause();
              if(showToastMessage!=null)
                {
                showToastMessage.cancel();
                }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to keep track of your Toasts. Keep your Toast objects around and then on onPause or whatever you loop through them calling toast.cancel(). That will close that toast. This will also allow unlikely but possible outside-of-your-app Toast messages from being force-closed by you.

Answer (score 0):

Toast messages are designed to notify the user of an important message. This is the reason they are queued and shown anyway. Toast messages were not intended to be sent in large numbers. (large numbers being greater than 1) If you have so much information to convey to the user, you should do so in a different manner. As they say in the bakery, thats the way the cookie crumbles.